# How to get next and previous date of selected date or current date by clicking arrow left Right

Tags: android, date

get next and the previous date of selected date or current date by clicking arrow left Right button like this image

[image]

Comment: If you are using LocalDate then you can use `localDate.minusDays(1)` and `localDate.plusDays(1)` to get previous or next day. More about LocalDate here https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/LocalDate available from api 26 if you target earlier devices you need to have desugaring enabled in project.

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
//for selected date add this line c.set(2021,2,2)
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
textview.setText(formattedDate);
```

For next date

```
previous.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
            formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
            textview.setText(formattedDate);
         }
      });
```

For previous date

```
next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
            textview.setText(formattedDate);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use old `Calendar` and `SimpleDateForamt` apis, it's [outdated and troublesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api)

Use `LocalDateTime` to get the system date and time.

Current Date

```
val dateTime = LocalDateTime.now()   // current date
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)  // date time formatter
Log.d("Date:", "parssed date ${dateTime.format(formatter)}")
```

For Previous Date

```
button.setOnClickListener { 
        val previousDate = dateTime.minusDays(1)
        Log.d("Date:", "previous date ${previousDate.format(formatter)}")
}
```

For Next Date

```
button.setOnClickListener {
        val nextDate = dateTime.plusDays(1)
        Log.d("Date:", "next date ${nextDate.format(formatter)}")
}
```

**Output**:
Current date - Dec 9, 2021
Previous date - Dec 8, 2021
Next date -  Dec 10, 2021

**Note**: `LocalDateTime` only works in android 8 and above, to use it below android 8 [enable desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring)